# PromQL how to use changes function with a metric consisting of or condition

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator

I want to write a query that will compute the changes to my metric and use value 1 as a starting point. The problem with changes is that it does not return 1 at the start of the data points. I want the graph to have a spike at the very start and then go back to 0. So far I have tried the following query

```
metirc{public!="0"} or on() vector(0)
```

This returns 2 time series and I am not able to use changes on this result

```
changes((metric{public!="0"} or on() vector(0)) [1d])
```

This gives an error that range query can only be applied to vector selectors. I just want the changes graph to show a spike when the value is first time existing in the table

Answer (score 0):

`vector(0)` wouldn't be suitable for this. It produces vector without labels, and adding needed labels would be cumbersome at best.

If you need single 1 in "beginning" of data returned by your query, you could use something like

```
changes(metirc{public!="0"}[1d]) or ((1 + metirc{public!="0"} offset -5m)/(1 + metirc{public!="0"} offset -5m))
```

It returns usual changes if metric is present, and 1 (with correct labels) if metric will be present in five minutes from timestamp.

But beware of this query behavior in case of temporarily metrics absence. It will produce ones as placeholder for last five minutes of absence.